# How to prevent page refreshing with changing window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, postback, refresh

I am changing the URL with window.location but it postsback and jumb to the top

```
function ImageClick(Lnk) {
    window.location.href = Lnk;
    return false;                
}
```

how can i make such performance that happened here when u click next `http://wonderwall.msn.com/movies/costume-institute-gala-at-the-met-12342.gallery?photoId=51564#!wallState=0__%2Fmovies%2Fcostume-institute-gala-at-the-met-12342.gallery%3FphotoId%3D51578`

Comment: Can you please try to be more clear?

Comment: That is not a "postback". Stop speaking in ASP.NET when it's completely unrelated.

Comment: Ok i just don't want the page to blink and jump to top

Comment: please check this performance http://wonderwall.msn.com/#!wallState=0__%2Fmovies%2Fcostume-institute-gala-at-the-met-12342.gallery%3FphotoId%3D51571

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: Why not edit the post?

Answer (score 1):

The keyword you're looking for is "Ajax" :)

Answer (score 1):

AJAX!

Asynchronous JavaScript and XML (although JSON(P) is mostly used these days). AJAJ?

Answer (score 0):

See this previous post:

[Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

I strongly suggest against this as it's frowned upon however, as is mentioned in the above post. If you are going to use the code, do remember it's not cross-browser compatible.